# How to add/remove consumers at run time in spring amqp?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have certain number of listeners running on each server which is equal to listener concurrency. Below is configuration

```
<rabbit:listener-container
    connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" concurrency="${compute.listener.concurrency}"
    requeue-rejected="false" prefetch="1">
    <rabbit:listener queues="${compute.queue}" ref="computeListener"
        method="run" />
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

Is there any way to add/remove number of listeners on any server at run time while my job is running without making changes to this setting and redeploying the application ?

May be some command line tool to add/remove number of consumers at run time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it manually: `SimpleMessageListenerContainer.setConcurrentConsumers()/setMaxConcurrentConsumers()`, there is need to specify the `id` for the `<rabbit:listener>` element. And using it you can get the bean from application context and invoke those methods with appropriate values.

There is no any spcific tool to do it externally.

However you can do it e.g. using Spring Integration's `<int-stream:stdin-channel-adapter>`. Or write some `@ManagedResource` and expose it to the JMX with `@@ManagedAttribute`s to change those values for underlying `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`